# Resources in Spring/Restlet project instantiated twice per request

Tags: spring, restlet, spring-3, applicationcontext, restlet-2.0

I have a Spring 3.1/Restlet 2.0 web application. I see that the beans for my resources are instantiated twice per request. I suspect that this is because an instance is created for both the root and servlet contexts, but I can't figure out how to either merge the contexts or only instantiate the beans only in the servlet's context.

Any help would be appreciated. I have included what I believe are the relevant snippets below.

My web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="restlet-basecamp" version="2.5"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <display-name>Integration API</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>integrationApi</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.restlet.ext.spring.RestletFrameworkServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>integrationApi</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

integrationApi-servlet.xml contains the following:

```
<!-- Scan the package for classes to inject -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.company.api" />

<!-- Setup the main component -->
<bean id="integrationApiComponent" class="org.restlet.ext.spring.SpringComponent">
    <property name="defaultTarget" ref="integrationApiAppliction" />
</bean>

<!-- Setup the router -->
<bean id="integrationApiAppliction" name="root"
    class="com.company.api.application.IntegrationApiApplication">
    <property name="root" ref="router" />
</bean>

<!-- Define the router -->
<bean name="router" class="org.restlet.ext.spring.SpringBeanRouter" />

<!-- Routes and resources -->
<bean name="/v1/foo/{val}"
    class="com.company.api.resource.FooResource"
    scope="prototype" autowire="byName" />

<bean name="/v1/status"
    class="com.company.api.resource.StatusResource"
    scope="prototype" autowire="byName" />

<!-- Load the properties -->
....
<!-- Camel Endpoints -->
....
<!-- Configure the ActiveMQ component -->
....
<!-- Services -->
```

Comment: Let's see the rest of your deployment descriptor.

Comment: I have edited the question to include the full web.xml.

Comment: Can you also clarify where you are using your beans? (I don't know restlet).

Comment: The beans that are scoped "prototype" are attached to the URIs in their names and created for each request. Other beans are injected into these beans.